# why xpath works in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Below xpath works in firefox but not in chrome

any ideas??

```
/html/body/app/div/compliance/div/main/reporting/div[1]/div[2]/download-button/iron-dropdown/div/div/button[2]
```

Comment: XPath that starts with `/html` is always brittle and often, as you found out, not portable. Find some tutorials on the net on how to write better XPaths.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing screams at me as being incorrect about your xpath, but without knowing the page you are interacting with it's hard to tell.

Have you tried searching that xpath in chrome dev tools?

Also if possible try to key off of attributes the button has rather than it's index and path. That generally makes for a more robust Xpath.

E.G. `//button[@attribute="specificAttributeValue"]`

The `//` indicates that it is a relative path.

Comment: `//` is **not** relative; `./` would indicate relative XPath. `//` is just shortened.